# Silverlights Dataform with MVVM and WCF Ria Services

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, dataform

Good evening,

I am looking for someone to help me with my understanding of how to incorporate the Silverlight DataForm with my ViewModel that using WCF Ria Services. What I am trying to accomplish is using the DataForm manage my collection of entity and utilize its built in navigation, Add, Edit and Delete functionality. Howerver, I am having trouble tying it all together with my ViewModel and Ria Services.

From my understanding, the DataForm needs to be bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. However when I query from the WCF Ria Service context. ie.

```
_context.Load(_context.GetAllCustomersQuery(), loadCustomersQueryCallback, true);
```

I will receive back an IQueryable in the callback method, which i would have to cast as an `ObservableCollection<T>` like so?

`Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(_context.Customers);`

Customers is a property in my ViewModel  like so...

```
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            if (_customers != value)
            {
                _customers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
            }
        }
    }
```

The DataForm is bound to the Customers Property of the ViewModel and I am able to see the data from my datasource, I can navigate between entities, I can edit an existing entity and persist the changes back to the database however I cannot add or delete entites.

Is what I'm doing with the Customers property correct? have I "disconnected" from the context by casting into a new ObservableCollection and therefore have not actually added or removed the entities from the context?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I think you hit on the issue in your last question. When you create a new ObservableCollection, you've disconnected from collection change tracking (adds and deletes). Instead of using OC, there are a number of other options worth considering. In your case, it looks like EntitySet or EntityList may be the best options. For a full rundown of these types, take a look at my post on [collection binding in RIA Services SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/12/02/collection-binding-options-in-wcf-ria-services-sp1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
Customers.Clear(); // Or dispose every customer if it is Disposable
Customers = new ObservableCollection(result.ToList());
```